# Yolov8 Pyinstaller exe file constantly reruns itself

Tags: python, pytorch, pyinstaller, yolo, yolov8

I converted a very simple application that I developed with Yolov8 to exe with pyinstaller. The script runs very well but when I run the exe file it constantly reruns itself. My codes are as follows:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("best.pt")
results = model.track("./last.mp4", show=True)
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCUkv.png)

Pyinstaller command to convert it to exe file:

```
pyinstaller main.py --no-console
```

Additional note:
After converting the script to an exe file, I manually created the ultralytics/cfg/default.yaml file at the location of the exe file because it gave an error that ultralytics could not find the default.yaml file.

I also tried converting into onefile but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the issue is related to the 'cpuinfo' module. I don't yet know the reason, but removing the relevant code from the Ultralytics codebase resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### How I overcame this issue:

I encountered a similar issue to what the above query described. In my case, I faced the error while utilizing **--onefile** with **pyinstaller**.

### To tackle this problem:

- Use the **--onedir** command alongside pyinstaller.
- After generating the .exe, check if it's working properly. If the
  error persists, indicating the absence of 'data.yaml':
- Verify if the 'ultralytics' folder is created by pyinstaller; if not,
  proceed to the next step.
- Manually create the 'ultralytics\cfg' directory under the same
  directory as the generated .exe.
- Add the 'data.yaml' file within the 'ultralytics\cfg' directory.

This adjustment enabled the .exe file to run successfully without encountering the missing 'data.yaml' error.

Hope this workaround helps!

Answer (score 0):

`cpuinfo` module indeed seems to be the culprit.

The solution is to call `freeze_support()` (see https://github.com/orgs/ultralytics/discussions/1356)

```
from multiprocessing import freeze_support

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Pyinstaller fix
    freeze_support()
```